# How to draw a smooth oval in canvas

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas, fabricjs

I am trying to draw a smooth oval using ctx.clip property in my canvas.I have done with drawing part i am facing problem with oval arc line clarity.Any one have any idea regarding this just let me know?
Here is my code.

```
<canvas id="c" width="400" height="400"></canvas>


var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var cx=180;
var cy=200;
var w=300;
var h=250;
    // Quadratric curves example
    ctx.beginPath();
    var lx = cx - w/2,
        rx = cx + w/2,
        ty = cy - h/2,
        by = cy + h/2;
    var magic = 0.551784;
    var xmagic = magic*w/2;
    var ymagic = h*magic/2;
    ctx.moveTo(cx,ty);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(cx+xmagic,ty,rx,cy-ymagic,rx,cy);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(rx,cy+ymagic,cx+xmagic,by,cx,by);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(cx-xmagic,by,lx,cy+ymagic,lx,cy);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(lx,cy-ymagic,cx-xmagic,ty,cx,ty);

    ctx.fill();
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.clip();



var text;
text = new fabric.Text('Honey', {
  fontSize: 50,
  left: 150,
  top: 150,
  lineHeight: 1,
  originX: 'left',
  fontFamily: 'Helvetica',
  fontWeight: 'bold'
});
canvas.add(text);
```

[Here is my fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/xadqg/6/)

You can see this output over here the line border of oval not much clear.
[image: Here is output of screen shot]

Comment: A one pixel line is not going to be very clear, you'd have to anti-alias it

Comment: what exacly @JuanMendes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**One problem is in the nature of your display screen...**

Since pixels are rectangles and you're drawing a curve, your result will have "jaggies" as the curve tries to fit itself in rectangular spaces.

You can use an optical illusion to trick the eye into seeing a less jagged oval.

**An optical trick:**

Reduce the contrast between the background color and the oval color.

This is not a cure...the jaggies are still there.

But the eye recognizes less contrast and perceives the oval as more smooth.

So if your design accommodates this style change, this optical illusion might help.

Here's code and a Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/vDWR3/

```
var cx=180;
var cy=200;
var w=300;
var h=250;

// Start with a less-contrasting background
ctx.fillStyle="#ddd";
ctx.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);

ctx.beginPath();
var lx = cx - w/2,
    rx = cx + w/2,
    ty = cy - h/2,
    by = cy + h/2;
var magic = 0.551784;
var xmagic = magic*w/2;
var ymagic = h*magic/2;
ctx.moveTo(cx,ty);
ctx.bezierCurveTo(cx+xmagic,ty,rx,cy-ymagic,rx,cy);
ctx.bezierCurveTo(rx,cy+ymagic,cx+xmagic,by,cx,by);
ctx.bezierCurveTo(cx-xmagic,by,lx,cy+ymagic,lx,cy);
ctx.bezierCurveTo(lx,cy-ymagic,cx-xmagic,ty,cx,ty);

ctx.fillStyle="#555";
ctx.strokeStyle=ctx.fillStyle;
ctx.lineWidth=1.5;
ctx.stroke();
```

Answer (score 3):

try this it will help you
//Script

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
 var w;
 var h;
 var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
 w=canvas.width / 4;
 h=canvas.height / 2.4;
canvas.clipTo = function(ctx) {
 ctx.save();
 ctx.scale(2, 1.2);
 ctx.arc(w, h, 90, 0, 2 * Math.PI, true);
 ctx.stroke();
 ctx.restore();
}
```

Fiddle [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xadqg/15/)

Answer (score 1):

Here is another alternative routine, but it looks visually the same as the other methods. This is primarily to do with the finite resolution of the display device, though you may be able to make some improvement using a thicker pencil, optical illusions or performing some anti-aliasing. Otherwise I think you will have to accept what you have.

Javascript

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c'),
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"),
    steps = 100,
    step = 2 * Math.PI / steps,
    h = 200,
    k = 180,
    r = 150,
    factor = 0.8,
    theta,
    x,
    y,
    text;

ctx.beginPath();

for (theta = 0; theta < 2 * Math.PI; theta += step) {
    x = h + r * Math.cos(theta);
    y = k - factor * r * Math.sin(theta);
    ctx.lineTo(x, y);
}

ctx.closePath();
ctx.fill();
ctx.stroke();
ctx.clip();

text = new fabric.Text('Honey', {
    fontSize: 50,
    left: 150,
    top: 150,
    lineHeight: 1,
    originX: 'left',
    fontFamily: 'Helvetica',
    fontWeight: 'bold'
});

canvas.add(text);
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/QHQWa/)

Note: by changing the number of steps and the factor, you can create other shapes: circles, squares, hexagons, other polygons ....

Comment: +1 And here is a variant which allows specifying x and y radius: http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/VrKJV/

Comment: @Ken That appears to give a nice anti aliased effect.

Comment: @ken I notice it looks the same as all the other methods once `ctx.clip()` is called [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/8gG9p/)

Comment: Without knowing fabric I would assume it uses a double resolution approach. Just increase the `lineWidth` to 1.5 or 2 to compensate. http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/8gG9p/1/ The problem is that the double resolution is then being drawn at half size to main canvas which will also reduce the effect of the anti-aliasing effect.

Comment: Yes, I still believe that a thicker pen is the best solution to the OPs question.

Answer (score 0):

```
<canvas id="thecanvas" width="400" height="400"></canvas>

<script>
var canvas = document.getElementById('thecanvas');

if(canvas.getContext) 
{
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  drawEllipse(ctx, 10, 10, 100, 60);
  drawEllipseByCenter(ctx, 60,40,20,10);
}

function drawEllipseByCenter(ctx, cx, cy, w, h) {
  drawEllipse(ctx, cx - w/2.0, cy - h/2.0, w, h);
}

function drawEllipse(ctx, x, y, w, h) {
  var kappa = .5522848,
      ox = (w / 2) * kappa, // control point offset horizontal
      oy = (h / 2) * kappa, // control point offset vertical
      xe = x + w,           // x-end
      ye = y + h,           // y-end
      xm = x + w / 2,       // x-middle
      ym = y + h / 2;       // y-middle

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(x, ym);
  ctx.bezierCurveTo(x, ym - oy, xm - ox, y, xm, y);
  ctx.bezierCurveTo(xm + ox, y, xe, ym - oy, xe, ym);
  ctx.bezierCurveTo(xe, ym + oy, xm + ox, ye, xm, ye);
  ctx.bezierCurveTo(xm - ox, ye, x, ym + oy, x, ym);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.stroke();
}

</script>
```

http://jsbin.com/ovuret/2/edit

Comment: This is also not to much clear when i integrate this in my code

Comment: http://jsbin.com/ecipiq/5/edit checkout anti-aliasing approach, don't see m uch difference tbh.

Answer (score 0):

A possibility is to use a thicker line, it's not great but it's better

```
ctx.lineWidth = 3;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xadqg/7/

I also noticed that using `quadraticCurveTo` seems to anti alias the line http://jsfiddle.net/d4JJ8/298/ I didn't change your code to use it but the jsfiddle I posted shows that it's true. You should modify your code and try it

Comment: I saw it but when i select the text its going to unclear again.

Comment: @SanjayNakate I don't see what you're observing, it looks exactly the same when I select the text (in Chrome)

Comment: I think that a thicker pencil is about as simple and as good as it gets. +1

Comment: In chrome it working little bit fine i hope you right having issue with Mozilla @JuanMendes